# Cross-compiling backports for kernel 3.0

Tags: kernel-modules, cross-compilation, backports

I am trying to compile [backports](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) (I have chosen latest [5.6.8-1] release) for an i.MX35 (armv6) Embedded Linux system with the provided toolchain **(arm-fsl-gnueabi-gcc 4.6.2, a different compiler is not an option)** and the BSP kernel **(3.0, a different kernel is, sadly, not an option)**.

[The relevant page](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Documentation) claims that

> Every backports release has been test compiled for usage against all
>   supported kernels. The oldest release is (currently) 3.0.

so I should be fine, although, as written below, I am sure they did not test this release against 3.0, *because it simply cannot be compiled for that release without manual interventions*.

I have [re]built the kernel source tree and followed [instructions under "cross-compiling"](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Documentation/packaging) for out-of-tree backports building. Then first I selected, via `menuconfig`, a bunch of USB WiFi drivers, but due to compile errors, I deleted and reextracted the tarball and did (since they claim

> Its understood users may not know how to configure the backports
>   package, just like they may not know how to configure the Linux
>   kernel, so a short cut is provided with default configuration files
>   that can be used to only build their drivers / subsystems of interest.

) just a `defconfig-mwifiex` to be sure I was not doing anything wrong in the configuration. Yes, I'm such an hopeless optimistic guy.

I had to expunge some "not-too-much-backported" functions that depends on functionalities not found in 3.0:

1. change `__atomic_add_unless` to `atomic_add_unless` in `backport-include/linux/atomic.h`
2. change `debug_fs_create_xul` in `backport-include/linux/debugfs.h` to unconditionally call `debug_fs_create_x32` since `debug_fs_create_x64` does not exist; since the conditional version dispatches basing on the size of `unsigned long`, that is 32 bit on this platform, the latter won't be called anyway.
3. commented out `netdev_upper_dev_link` stuff in `backport-include/linux/netdevice.h` (from line 360 onwards) because it does not exists in 3.0 but only in some later release. Anyway is only called by *a module I'm not compiling* (actually, it does not even appear in menuconfig due to the base kernel configuration) so it is safe.
4. placed under `#ifdef CONFIG_PCI` the definition of `pcie_find_root_port` because it calls/{depends on} a chain that is `#ifdef`ed with the same variable in `backport-include/linux/pci.h`
5. `#ifdef`ed `pm_runtime_active` in `backport-include/linux/pm_runtime.h` with `CONFIG_PM_RUNTIME` since the struct members it uses are under the same `#ifdef`
6. `#ifdef`ed `NETLINK_CB(in_skb).sk` accesses in `compat/backport-genetlink.c` with `LINUX_IS_VERSION_GEQ(3, 10, 0)` because the `sk` struct member was added only in that release.

Unfortunately `net/wireless/trace.c` has a problem with `TP_PROTO` expansions, so GCC errors out with a lot of `error: expected ')' before 'struct'`, and I had not managed to solve those. Any ideas?

If not, any **really tested on 3.0** backports release (hoping to have a good bunch of battle-tested WiFi USB drivers available)?